# Libgdx: GLFW may only be used on the main thread. This check may be disabled with Configuration.GLFW_CHECK_THREAD0

Tags: java, terminal, libgdx

Running maven command on terminal to execute my Libgdx application, I get the error: `GLFW may only be used on the main thread. This check may be disabled with Configuration.GLFW_CHECK_THREAD0.` The command that I am using to run is `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=net.game.Main`.

Many answers on the internet told me to use `-XstartOnFirstThread`, but I already added it by doing `export MAVEN_OPTS="-XstartOnFirstThread`. I also tried using `StartupHelper`, but it did not recognize main class.